# How use Regex Library Using C With Mingw-GCC On Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, mingw

I Want Build a Windows App(`.exe`) at my linux Arch system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main()
{
//regcomp()...
//regexec()...
//regfree()...
}
```

---

### $ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc nc.c -o nc.exe(this is not work)

```
nc.c:7:10: fatal error: regex.h: No such file or directory
 #include <regex.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

### $ gcc nc.c -o nc(this is work)

can not build `.exe` with `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` , this show error about `#include <regex.h>`.

but can compile with 'gcc` for linux.

---

how can fix problem of `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` ?

---

also i download `mingw-libgnurx-2.5.1-src.tar.gz`

### $ ./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32

```
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc... x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking whether x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc accepts the -mthreads option... yes
checking whether x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc accepts the -mtune=pentium3 option... no
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-lib... no
checking for lib... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

### $ make

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -mthreads -g -O2 -I .   -c -o regex.o regex.c
In file included from regex.c:61:0:
regex_internal.h:424:0: warning: "alloca" redefined
 # define alloca(size)   __builtin_alloca (size)

In file included from /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdlib.h:695:0,
                 from regex_internal.h:27,
                 from regex.c:61:
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/malloc.h:183:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define alloca(x) __builtin_alloca((x))

In file included from regex.c:64:0:
regcomp.c: In function ‘parse_dup_op’:
regcomp.c:2513:39: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     postorder (elem, mark_opt_subexp, (void *) (long) elem->token.opr.idx);
                                       ^
regcomp.c: In function ‘mark_opt_subexp’:
regcomp.c:3725:19: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
   int idx = (int) (long) extra;
                   ^
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -mthreads -g -O2 -I . -shared -o libgnurx-0.dll -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Wl,--out-implib,libgnurx.dll.a regex.o
cp -p libgnurx.dll.a libregex.a
```

---

### Install PCRE:

### $ sudo pacman -S pcre

```
warning: pcre-8.41-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) pcre-8.41-1

Total Installed Size:  3.38 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                     [######################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                   [######################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                        [######################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                  [######################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                [######################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) reinstalling pcre                            [######################] 100%
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
```

### $ sudo pacman -S pcre2

```
warning: pcre2-10.23-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) pcre2-10.23-1

Total Installed Size:  3.22 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                     [######################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                   [######################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                        [######################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                  [######################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                [######################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) reinstalling pcre2                           [######################] 100%
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check gnulib and see if it provides a Windows-compatible `<regex.h>`.  [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) has definitely been ported to Windows, and it offers a [`<regex.h>` replacement](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2posix.html).  PCRE has also been packaged for Arch Linux for mingw-w64 cross compilation, in the [mingw-w64-pcre2](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mingw-w64-pcre2/) package (since you appear to be using Arch Linux).

Stay away from `mingw-libgnurx-2.5.1-src.tar.gz`.  The warnings show that it is not compatible with x86-64 because `long` on 64-bit Windows is only 32 bits, and as the warnings show, the library authors clearly did not anticipate this.

Comment: $ `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc nc.c -o nc.exe -Wall` : 
fatal error: pcre2posix.h: No such file or directory `#include <pcre2posix.h>`

Comment: I think you need the [`mingw-w64-pcre2`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mingw-w64-pcre2/) package, but I'm not familiar with Arch Linux.

Comment: I try to install , https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mingw-w64-readline/ , and now is installed.

Comment: `  if (regcomp(&regexCompiled, regexString, REG_EXTENDED))
    {
      printf("Error\n");
      return 1;
    };
    regfree(&regexCompiled);`

Comment: `$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc dfgdfg.c -o fff.exe  -lpcre2-8`
/tmp/ccjLYe2n.o:dfgdfg.c:(.text+0x6c9): undefined reference to _imp__regcomp
/tmp/ccjLYe2n.o:dfgdfg.c:(.text+0x733): undefined reference to _imp__regexec
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: `$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc nc.c -o nc.exe  -lpcre2-8 -lpcre2-posix` Execute , and no error.

Comment: I tried only the `-regex` flag and my program (`md2roff`) compiled flawlessly...